# Ubuntu server mounted in read-only?

Tags: ubuntu, fsck, read-only, readwrite

This morning my Ubuntu server suddenly appeared in read-only mode.

Google says this can happen after updates.

I restarted the server and it booted with fsck errors:

```
Inodes that were parts of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
/dev/mapper/vg0-root: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: RUN fsck MANUALLY
fsck died with exit status 4
```

Google says you can only run `fsck -n` on read-only. I will runn that now nd hope to fix the inconstencies.

How can I undo the realy-only mounting of the root file system? Is it safe?

I'm not experienced much in administrating so I'd prefer host support, but it's the holidays...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, mounted file system are setup with `errors=remount-ro` option which is normal.
This means that if your system encounter a disk problem/inconsistency it will set the FS read-only.

`fsck -n` will not repair/fix anything, it will just report problems.

Badly, to remount root file system read/write you will have to reboot your machine.

At boot the system will certainly perform a `fsck` with repair option. If it doesn't, reboot your machine in single user mode (recovery mode) and perform a `fsck -r` (repair) by yourself.

Comment: Thanks. `fsck -r` did the trick and it booted without read-only mode :)